# Using wildcard and regex in find

Tags: bash, find, glob, quotes

I want to use `find` to list specific files using wildcard or regular expression.

For instance, I am currently using the following bash code to list all files starting with `A`.

```
nm="$2"  # user passes wildcard "A*" in $nm.
find $dir -name $nm
```

But one problem is that I don't want Bash to expand the wildcard being passed by the user.

I constructed the following bash function

```
mse ()
{

 local incl=() 

 local iarg=0  narg="$#"

 IFSPREV="$IFS"  # Save IFS (splits arguments on whitespace by default)
 IFS=" |="         # Split arguments on " " and "="
 set -- $*       # Set positional parameters to command line arguments
 IFS="$IFSPREV"  # Set original IFS

 while (( $# > 0  )); do
   iarg=$(( iarg + 1 ))
   case "$1" in
     ("--incl") incl+=("$2") ; echo "Test: $2" ; shift 2 ;;
   esac
 done

 echo "\$@: $@"
 echo "incl: ${incl[@]}"
 }
```

Then I run the function in the terminal

```
mse -d /media/hag/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/ --incl="A*"
```

which gives

```
incl: Admir
```

The result is wrong because it is picking up the directory name `Admir` that shows up it the current working directory.

And for passing regular expressions, how should the find command be constructed?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
find "$dir" -name "$nm"
```

(Double) quotation marks prevent the expansion of wildcards.

Answer (score -1):

To actually use **regular expressions** with `find`, pass the output of `find` to `grep`, for example:

```
find "$dir" | grep "$nm"
```

For example, I frequently use this variation:

```
find "$dir" | grep -P "$nm"
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: at least the GNU and FreeBSD versions of `find` support regexes, and I'm pretty sure `grep -P` is specific to GNU grep. (Plus piping to `grep` would cause issues if any names contain newlines)

Comment: @ilkkachu I frequently use Perl regexes using `grep -P`, as I mentioned. Does `find` support this regex flavor? If not, my answer has potential uses not found using `find` alone. I agree that newlines, etc may cause issues. But for the case shown by the OP, this is fine - they simply print the `find` results into STDOUT. Perhaps I should add a warning about the newlines, etc, for those who pipe the results into other programs...

Comment: I woold like to use find as it provides support for wildcards and regex.  But currently the problem is that the variable being passed when calling the function is expanded.

Comment: I have added the code through which I pass the function arguments,  I got a hunch that the problem is i how I am parsing the arguments. I have constrained the function better so to be succinct.